# Can a news article borrow quotes from other publications' articles?

Tags: journalism

Let's say publication A is writing a feature about a mature story that has already hit the hard news rounds of publications B, C, and D.

Can publication A quote interviews from B, C, and D's articles (with attributions, of course)?

Example:

> A John Doe told Publication B: "..."

> "..." said Dr. Dae, according to Publication C.

What's the best practice for this sort of thing?

Comment: the policy of any individual newspaper is up to the editor/management of that newspaper. There is no consistent answer as some journals pride themselves on being news generators with original reporting, while others are news aggregators that rely on AP Wire (etc). Still others appeal to political or populist biases, selectively-quoting other news sources with intentionally less 'transparent' attributions.